# Как задать максимальное время ожидания загрузки страницы?

Tags: java, android, webview

1)Как в WebView задать максимальное время ожидания загрузки страницы?

2)Чему равно ожидание по умолчанию?

Comment: Лучше подзапросами догружать страницу, либо делать flush. Пользователи очень не любят когда страница висит, могут запросить её повторно раз 10 - и повесят сервак)))

Comment: @nick_n_a, может и лучше, но интересуют ответы на данные вопросы, в документации их не замечаю, может плохо смотрю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы, этого нет в документации. Более того, я не нашёл этого и в исходном коде. А тот факт, что моя тестовая программка терпеливо 5 минут ждала ответа от моего же тестового web-сервера, наводит на мысли, что таймаута по умолчанию вообще нет. Остаётся только обходиться подобными костылями:

```
public class TimedWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    private boolean timeout;
    private int delay = 1000;

    public TimedWebViewClient() {}

    public TimedWebViewClient(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        timeout = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(timeout) {
                    view.stopLoading();
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Timeout!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        timeout = false;
    }
}

webView.setWebViewClient(new TimedWebViewClient());
```

Или использовать не родную реализацию WebView, например CordovaWebView.

Comment: 1)по умолчанию время ожидания загрузки какое?
2)чем данный код мне поможет если дефолтное время будет меньше чем нужно мне?

Comment: Развернул ответ.